# Opening multiple text files from a location

Tags: python

I'm trying to open 583 text files from a location. I need to find similarities between these files so I can join them in a database. My thinking was that Python would be suited for this, but I'm not even able to open the files..

```
    from os import listdir, chdir, getcwd
    path = (r'...\Text')
    chdir(path)
    files = [f for f in listdir(path)]
    active = []

    for bestand in files:
        with open(bestand) as x:
            active.append(x)

    print(active)
```

The result I'm getting is some file names with a mode and encoding. Here is a example:

```
     <_io.TextIOWrapper name='To-do.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Would like to hear if it's possible what I want to achieve. I appreciated a push in the right direction instead of a fully working code.

Thanks!

Edit: New problem I'm facing. I want all the column names as keys in a dictionary and the data as the values. Current code give me the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

```
from os import listdir, chdir, getcwd
from os.path import isfile, join
path = (r'...\Text')
chdir(path)
files = [f for f in listdir(path)]
active = []
values = {}

for bestand in files:
    if bestand.lower().endswith(('.txt')):
        with open(bestand) as x:
            active.append(x.read())

for line in active:
    if ',' not in line:
        continue

    #print("LINE: ", line)
    for key, value in line.strip().split(',', 1).items():
        values[key] = value
print(values)
```

Comment: If `x` is afile and you want to read the contents, you'll want something like `x.read()` or `x.readlines()`

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPursell. Tried readlines() before but it wouldn't work. Now it gives me strange error: Traceback (most recent call last):
      x.readlines()
  File "path\Desktop\Python\Python 3.7\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 77: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: use `with open(bestand, mode='utf-8') as x:` instead, as a general rule, utf-8 > default windows encoding (cp1252)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read after you open the file. The open method opens the file and returns a TextIOWrapper object but does not read the files content.

I am editing your code that gives a list of texts in these files:

```
from os import listdir, chdir, getcwd
path = (r'...\Text')
chdir(path)
files = [f for f in listdir(path)]
active = []

for bestand in files:
    with open(bestand) as x:
        active.append(x.read())

print(active)
```

The read method in append call does the work. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks that worked. I'm stuck on a different issue now. I need to put all the colomn names as keys and the data as their values. I've edited the original post

Comment: Can you share more information on the type of text data that we are dealing with here? Which columns and data are you talking of?

Comment: Hi Roshani. Data like this: http://prntscr.com/l6avz3 - Every data file is different except for the timestamp. So different headers / data. I'm trying to compare these files based on their headers and data to see if I can find similarities

Comment: @Frankicks So once you have each comma separated text file as string element in the list, store it to dataframe and you may want to use to_dict method of pandas to convert dataframe to dictionary with header names as keys.

Comment: How would I put my text files list in a dataframe?